# Add new extension to nodejs dynamic import

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-import

How do I add an new file extension to Nodejs dynamic import?
I want to add my own filetype, lets call it .jszip. (No, this is just an example and what I actually want has nothing to do with zip).

Say I have 
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "scripts": {
    "zip": "node --experimental-modules test.js"
 }
}
```

test.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Module = require('module');

function loadJsZip(module, filename) {
  console.log('In loadJsZip');
  const content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
  // Do something to content
  module._compile(content, filename);
}

require.extensions['.jszip'] = loadJsZip;
Module._extensions['.jszip'] = loadJsZip;


function loadJs(relativePath) {
   import(f).then((module) => {
    console.log(`imported from ${filename}:${module}`);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(`While importing:${err}`);
  });
}

loadJs('./testfile.jszip');
```

I am getting:

```
(node:20412) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
While importing:TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension: c:\...\testfile.jszip
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems other file types are not supported: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements

What worked for my case is getting the normal `require` and using that. So I'm importing `.graphql` files using:

```
import {createRequire} from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
require('graphql-import-node/register');

const myQuery = require('./myquery.graphql');
```

The graphql-import-node package does a `require.extension[] =` behind the scenes:

```
require.extensions['.graphql'] = loadPlainFile
```

But this is starting to become madness. You are probably better off using Webpack or something.